# 401 Unauthorized in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

> Component.tS

```
 this.service.getRoleData().subscribe((data: any)=>{
 console.log(data);    
});
```

> auth.service.ts

```
getRoleData(){
      var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Token' + 
      localStorage.getItem('token'));
      var options_role =  {
          headers: headers
      };
      return this.httpClient.get(environment.baseUrl +'api/auth/role/', 
          options_role); 
}
```

I am getting 401 Unauthorized. But in postman, i am getting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally tokens are set as like `Bearer xxxxx` in the header.

Try the setting the token in below way

```
getRoleData(){
      var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
      localStorage.getItem('token'));
      var options_role =  {
          headers: headers
      };
      return this.httpClient.get(environment.baseUrl +'api/auth/role/', 
          options_role); 
}
```